# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected up_sampling1d_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1108, 29430)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to make a convolutional autoencoder in Keras (Tensorflow backend), but it a problem with the dimensions of the last layer:

```
m.add(Embedding(features, embedding_dims, input_length=maxlen, input_shape=(features, ) ))
m.add(Dropout(0.2))

m.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1, input_shape=(features, ) ))
m.add(MaxPooling1D())

m.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1, input_shape=(features, ) ))
m.add(UpSampling1D(input_shape=(m.layers[-1].output_shape) ))
```

The model summary is as follows:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 11900, 60)         1765800   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 11900, 60)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 11898, 70)         12670     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 5949, 70)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 5947, 70)          14770     
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling1d_1 (UpSampling1 (None, 11894, 70)         0
```

The error message says that three dimensions are expected:
`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected up_sampling1d_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1108, 29430)`. However, the output of the last layer is (None, 5947, 70), which is three dimensions. (1108, 29430) is the dimensions of the original data (1108 samples with 29430 features).

Comment: what kind of data are you trying to encode? do you really need the embedding layer ?

Comment: @NassimBen I'm using text data. (It's a bag of words model at the moment, so order isn't preserved.)